# CSS align fullscreen image with max-height to middle

Tags: css, image, alignment, vertical-alignment

I am trying to create a simple gallery-like image viewer and I want to align the image to the centre and middle of the page.

This can be done simply using `table` and `table-row`, but only in the case when the image is smaller than 100% of the page. In the second case, I am able to align it simply through `text-align: centre` and `max-height: 100%`.

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/rtv393z7/

```
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <img style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 30px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/uRGZ0EE.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

But how to get it working in both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flex box like this:

```css
.flex-content{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
  <div class="flex-content" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <img style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 30px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/uRGZ0EE.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here a working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/rtv393z7/2/)

Or you can use `position: absolute` and `transform` like this:

```css
.center-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
    <div  class="center-content"  style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        <img style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 30px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/uRGZ0EE.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also note that I remove the `height: 100%` inline style from `.center-content`.

[Here the JSFiddle for this alternative](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/3c2nqn68/)

The thin is that the above example doesn't work in FF, I was seeing in Chrome.

So I fixed it like this:

```css
.center-content {
    position: relative;    
}

img{    
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);">
    <div  class="center-content"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <img style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 30px;" src="http://i.imgur.com/uRGZ0EE.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

[And here the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/71bnywht/)

Comment: Well, it seems working pretty good, but the image gets stretched sometimes (mostly when viewing in portrait resolution). Is that just browser bug, or how to avoid that? It happens in both Firefox and Chrome browsers, but I was not able to find out the exact conditions...

Comment: @Aslanex are you seeing that behavior in the JSFiddle?

Comment: Yes, tested on both JSFiddle and my own web. The alternative does not work too - when the page height is smaller than the image, the image does not zoom out, but remains cropped.

Comment: @Aslanex sorry I don't understand the behavior that you want, can you add more details of what you want to achieve, anyway this: "when the page height is smaller than the image, the image does not zoom out, but remains cropped." in the alternative solution is probably because you have 'padding: 30px' in 'img' remove it and let me no if that works as you want.

Comment: The image should remain fully visible at the page, while being scaled down proportionally. However, when the image is smaller than the page resolution, it should remain on its full original size and be positioned to the vertical and horizontal center of the page.

Comment: @Aslanex My alternative solution cover all your requirements, what is wrong with it?

Comment: No no, the image should be scaled to the page resolution, when bigger than the page. In your case, it does not scale vertically, and gets cropped in that case.

Comment: @Aslanex In chrome it works well but not in FF, So I update my answer to fix it, let me know if now it works as you want, finally :-)

Comment: Ok, seems definitely working well in all my browsers :)